# OperationalError: (2001, "Can't create UNIX socket (24)")

Tags: python, mysql, django, sockets, exception

I am using django-1.2 and python-2.6 and I am using mysql server.

After working for a while - selecting and updating records, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-269:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "dispatcher.py", line 42, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 80, in __len__  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 271, in iterator  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 677, in results_iter  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 731, in execute_sql  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 75, in cursor  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 297, in _cursor  
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect  
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__  
OperationalError: (2001, "Can't create UNIX socket (24)")
```

here are lines 41,42 of my `dispatcher.py`:

```
dataList = Mydata.objects.filter(date__isnull=True)[:chunkSize]
print '%s - DB worker finished reading %s entrys' % (datetime.now(),len(dataList))
```

Any clue why I get this error?
I tried googling but could not find an answer.

I am connecting to the db using django - (I am using localhost)

Comment: what does your mysql connection look like?

Comment: How many database connections are you initing?  Maybe you are running out of file descriptors...

Comment: Please try to connect with mysql cli client. If you can connect then try with django

Comment: i use django orm to connect, i dont know how many connections because django orm take care of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, errno==24 is defined like

```
#define EMFILE          24      /* Too many open files */
```

Which means you are running out of filedescriptors. Your app is "leaking" filedescriptors by opening them (and not closing them) again and again.

Comment: where do i open them ? and where should i close them ? isnt django should take care of this ?

Comment: Well ther error clearly originates from the Python `connections.py::init` function. So either the .py middleware is wrong, or you are using it wrong (you are leaking database connections, e.g. by calling init for every query)

Comment: @yossi: take a look at what [file descriptors](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations) are.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not forgetting to close file. But have too many files opened at the same time.