# When is a thread's run command terminated in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

In reading [this](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

> Once the thread’s activity is started, the thread is considered ‘alive’. It stops being alive when its run() method terminates – either normally, or by raising an unhandled exception.

and [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308166/in-python-when-threads-die), I am still not exactly sure when a Python thread "dies". If, for example I invoke a thread with something like this:

```
def preparemessage():
    print('test')

def notify(message):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=preparemessage, args=(message))
    thread.start()
```

Would the thread just terminate after printing "test"?

I.e. do these threads just terminate when the things they are responsible for finish? I realize that is not a great way of explaining things but I don't know how else to say it.  Is there a simple way to explain this?

Comment: The answer is yes. The thread will terminate soon as your preparemessage() worker finishes to do what its supposed to do. Normally you would run it on an infinite loop to keep the thread alive with some sleeps when there is no input data to work on. You would provide a sentinel (a flag) to tell the thread it can exit your infinite loop so that it can terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Once the target function has completely finished executing or some error has occurred the thread will be terminated.