# Mysql Error = Can't create UNIX socket (24)

Tags: mysql

I have got the following exception

Mysql Caught Exception = Can't create UNIX socket (24).

I know that UNIX system error 24. That's "too many open files."

I refered this question ,:[OperationalError: (2001, "Can't create UNIX socket (24)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292567/operationalerror-2001-cant-create-unix-socket-24)

But I need to understand the exact problem. 
In my code I execute multiple select query and store the result,not using free_result method in between.

Can it be the case of this error : Can't create UNIX socket (24)

Here is my  code :

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mysqlMutex);
    mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
    my_bool reconnect = 1;
    MYSQL* connection;
    mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);
    connection = mysql_real_connect( server,user,password, database_name, 0, NULL, 0 );
    if(connection == NULL)
    {
             //Connection failed.Exception Handling
    }
    //Execute query  :SELECT * from user ;
    mysql_query(mysql, getuser_query); 

     MYSQL_RES *mysql_res = mysql_store_result(mysql);

    // Query # 2
    // SELECT * from usergroup.
    mysql_query(m_pMysql, userGroup_query);
     mysql_res = mysql_store_result(mysql);
    // Query # 3
    // Query # 4
```

At the last:

```
    //free mysql memory
    mysql_free_result(mysql_res);
    mysql_close(mysql);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mysqlMutex);
```

Comment: I also meet this problem,First,I follow akostadinov answer to increase available FDs and decrease mysql's open_table_cache and max_connections.But it seem that it still happen through a long time.I think my code may have other problem,and I printf FDs,I find FDs that return is increase.So I think it may other palce not close FD.So I suggest you to see if there are others not close FDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are perhaps opening too many simultaneous connections to mysql server. You need to increase available FDs to mysql process. You can usually do so with `/etc/security/limits*` in your linux distro.
You can also look at this question: [Mysql decrease opened files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519166/mysql-decrease-opened-files)

Comment: Yes we do process large number of files on server. Is this the only solution ? To increase FD?

Comment: Can it be problem of programming ? As I have asked,I  store mysql result but do not execute free_result statement in between.

Comment: It seems you are closing connections properly. And mysql/mariaDB should not open new files for simple queries that do not involve temporary tables that do not fit into memory. Perhaps you can try using a connection pool shared between your executions but unless you spend a lot of time in application processing while connection stays open, then it wont help. By default max fds in most distros is 1024 which is pretty low. No need to fear increasing that to 10k or something. In manual you can see free result only consumes memory, not FDs: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.mysql-free-result.php